# which process has created a load spike on my server last week?

Tags: mysql, linux, unix

O.S.:Linux
MYSQL server

we got a load spike last week.

how can I find the process that has created the load spike on my server last week.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot triage the process that is in past-tense provided if you have below setup in-place.

1. Have a plugin to monitor your load avg/CPU/IO.
2. If any one of them seems to be breaching you may trigger a script to gather details for mysql and server processes and save it to a log_file with timestamp name.

   - mysql > show full processlist \G
   - ps -ef details.

By this way you can collate details when your usage goes peak. And you may check when you are awake in the day time.

Answer (score 2):

If you have the slow query log active, you might be able to identify a long running query during the timeframe of your load spike. This probably the only way to figure out the issue that has already occurred.

You can configure a script like [pt-stalk](http://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/2.1/pt-stalk.html) to try to capture future issues, however.

Here's an example to trigger data collection if you have more than 10 connections from host '10.0.0.23' [[src]](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2013/01/03/percona-toolkit-by-example-pt-stalk/):

```
pt-stalk --function processlist --variable Host\
 --match 10.0.0.23 --threshold 10 -- --defaults-file=./my.default.cnf
```